# Mapping values between JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, python, json, node.js

I seem to have run into a rather unusual problem. Using a form builder I am able to store and render an admin created form in JSON format like so:

**EDIT**: this is my pulled data from MongoDB hence the id, i directly push my generated JSON into Mongo, i eliminate the ID part on fetching the data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5985608427f8510788b468ab"),
    "fdata" : [
            {
                    "type" : "header",
                    "subtype" : "h1",
                    "label" : "Date Of Commencement"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "paragraph",
                    "subtype" : "p",
                    "label" : "The partnership business shall be deemed to have commenced on and from&nbsp;<div><br></div>"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "date",
                    "required" : true,
                    "label" : "Date Field",
                    "description" : "Date Of Commencement",
                    "className" : "form-control",
                    "name" : "date-1501913203863"
            }
    ]
 }
```

Once it is rendered and values are filled in by a user i receive the values at the back end like so: (NODEJS)

```
 {"date-1501913203863":"2017-08-12"}
```

Now I have to render the form back but with the filled values and it should look like a filled form. Is there a native way in JSON to do this? I was planning to go ahead with a python script to match the values to the fields but that seemed like overkill for this problem.

I hope to get some advise on this topic and not code. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"_id" : ObjectId("5985608427f8510788b468ab"),` isn’t JSON. Anyway, what’s the form builder?

Comment: yes you are right sir, i push the JSON directly into my MongoDB hence the ID, on retrieval i eliminate the id portion of it. The form builder is http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Well, you can use `JSON.parse` to convert your json to a javascript object and operate within javascript with that object.